# No default language could be detected for this app during deploy of Viber bot to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, viber, viber-bot-python

Does anyone know the reason for this error which came when I tried to upload my Viber bot to Heroku ?

```
No default language could be detected for this app.
```

I couldn’t find it in the given link also.

What should I do ?

[image]

Comment: Any feedback for this ?

Comment: Which language are you using? Which commands did you run? Did you provide a builpack like in this command example from their website `heroku create myapp --buildpack heroku/python`?

Answer (score 0):

Add file `runtime.txt` with following content, which stands for Python version you use and [Heroku supports](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version):

```
3.7.12
```